# Можно ли повысить свою эффективность работы в след. ситуации?

Tags: python

Хочу повысить эффективность своей работы. Заметил что я часто делаю такое:

1. Пишу код в IDE
2. Открываю Notepad++ для написани cmd-скрипта или python-скрипта
3. Открываю cmd.exe
4. Смотрю результаты в консоль и повторяю цикл

Замечу что скрипты бывают разные и каждый раз кастомные. Скрипты решают разные задачи от сбора какой-либо статистики и анализа логов до тестирования и генерации тест.данных. Причем вернувшись к работе в след. раз эти скрипты могут потерять актуальность и пишутся другие.

Это можно улучшить?

Я согласен что тесты можно оформить в виде unit-тестов или тулзы с подключением в виде post-build-события, но не все тесты нужно оформлять в таком виде. Иногда это просто необходимость в этом "сеансе работы" и после того как закончил, то вернувшись в след.раз они(тесты) уже, как правило, теряют актуальность

**UPD:**
Сейчас мне не хватает консоли в NetBeans. Из-за ее отсутствия мне приходится жать Win-R -> cmd.exe. Это "ломает" весь [сеанс работы](http://habrahabr.ru/post/103572/), т.к. отвлекаюсь.

P.S.:
Как создавать теги, а то не умею и следовательно не могу соотнести вопрос к нужной тематике

Comment: > Как создавать теги, а то не умею и следовательно не могу соотнести вопрос к нужной тематике

Просто указываете их в поле `Метки`, когда создаете вопрос.

Comment: Для начала, попробуйте обобщить имеющийся код.

Если какой-то скрипт (или часть скрипта) используется в нескольких проектах, возможно с некоторыми модификациями, постарайтесь вычленить общий код в функции, и сложить их в отдельную библиотеку. И стараться использовать и дальше.

Затем, я бы посоветовал перейти на unix shell вместо cmd.exe. Например, попробуйте [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/). Писать скрипты на bash на миллион порядков удобнее, чем на cmd.exe. Ещё одной альтернативой был бы Perl.

Comment: @VladD ну есть и вполне native-win реализации bash, zsh, ksh... А что касается конкуренции perl vs python -- так тут сложно советовать. Для однострочников perl однозначно лучше, но если строк больше -- то добавляются уже другие соображения. И зачем к питону добавлять ещё перл?

Comment: @alexlz: cygwin хорош тем, что с ним идёт сразу весь пакет: sed, grep, awk, bc, sort (и даже gcc и flex/bison, если надо).

Перл в дополнение к питону, мне кажется, нужен как продвинутый shell: для скриптов. Новый хороший язык не помешает, и вообще, «пусть расцветут тысячи цветов». Так что не _vs_, а _ad_.

Comment: @VladD:
Ваши:
>>Для начала, попробуйте обобщить имеющийся код.
Я же указал. Не получится! Каждый раз задачи разные! ;) Сегодня к примеру пишу детектирование вируса, а завтра это может быть проект специфичного блокнота для какого-нибудь клиента. А через два дня вообще оптимизатор виртуализованного кода в исполняемом файле. А через три дня... Это конечно все абстрактно, но мне хочется попытаться донести мысль что проекты бывают разные и обобщить не получится

Comment: @VladD «пусть расцветут тысячи цветов». Это вроде Конфуций? А за ним председатель Мао (незадолго до культурной революции, когда пришли юные садовники и лишние цветочки подстригли). Ну да ладно. perl -- сложный язык с неоднозначным синтаксисом и практически никакой типизацией. Одним из достоинств считают лаконичность, но. Где-то в начале 2000х А.Москаль (СПб) писал, что начал потихоньку переписывать живущие у них perl-скрипты на OCaml. Код становился короче...

(Да, про CPAN мне объяснять не надо)

Comment: @Nofate:
При попытке набрать новую несуществующую метку получаю ошибку с текстом в начале "Меток: эффективность-работы нет."

Comment: @sys_dev: Ну, если уж задачи совсем разные, значит, код не обобщается, пичалька. Но неужели хоть тестовый фреймворк нельзя отделить? (Нет — значит нет.)

@alexlz: Мао, Мао, конечно :-) Длинные скрипты на Perl по-моему оверкилл, но по выразительности с конструкциями типа `next if /^\s*#/;` редко какой язык сможет поспорить.

Comment: @VladD noch einmal для однострочников -- однозначно. А вот дальше... И какие скрипты относятся к длинным, если уж на php, который есть один из побочных детей перла, CMS'ы пишут...

Comment: @alexlz: PHP = Personal Home Page ^-P так что CMS имхо не лучшее его применение. И кроме того, PHP не дитя Perl'а, а бастард, так что судить о Perl'е по PHP не стоит. Я для себя считаю скрипт длиннее 100 строк кода длинным, but YMMV.

Comment: @VladD 

     Я для себя считаю скрипт длиннее 100 строк кода длинным

Скрипты менее 100 строк длиной на perl часто пишут благодаря библиотечным программам на perl/C совсем другой длины. Чудес не бывает. Если бы их не было (оверкилл), то перл не достиг бы теперешнего уровня. Ну а "бастард" или "побочный ребёнок" -- так это проблема чисто языковая.

Comment: Я - приверженец Windows, командные строки не люблю. Поэтому я в сходных случаях открывал (и не закрывал) редактор, в котором я делал заметки по работе и собирал кусочки скриптов. Потом собирал кусочки и копировал в терминал (тоже открытый всегда). Но в моём случае это были команды git, 1-4 строки за раз.



А про "Сегодня к примеру пишу детектирование вируса, а завтра это может быть проект специфичного блокнота" хочется сказать "невозможно автоматизировать хаос"

Comment: @Михаил М
>>Я - приверженец Windows, командные строки не люблю. 

Вот и зря! После того как программист начинает юзать консоль, даже такую убогую как в Windows его эффективность повышается в разы! А когда изучает PowerShell, то он понимает как много ему не хватало.

>>хочется сказать "невозможно автоматизировать хаос"

Буквально не давно Б.Гейтсу говорили "Вы рехнулись! Что люди будут делать с компьютером дома?". А что сейчас? Сейчас невозможно представить ни одного ученного, который бы не пользовался компьютером!

Можно говорить "это невозможно", а можно в очередной раз попытаться улучшить

Comment: @sys_dev, дайте пример-другой, когда командная строка может быть настолько эффективна? Или ссылочку на хорошую статью



>Буквально не давно Б.Гейтсу говорили...



Ну я немного в другом смысле говорил, но не суть. Пока у нас есть только 4 ваших пункта в вопросе и пара примеров в комментарии, поэтому только такие общие советы. Больше информации только у Вас, для Вас это не совсем хаос. Или дайте нам больше use cases. 



Хотя, если повезёт, кто-нибудь свой интересный пример из жизни вспомнит, может нам всем пригодится

Comment: > UPD: Сейчас мне не хватает консоли в
> NetBeans. Из-за ее отсутствия мне
> приходится жать Win-R -> cmd.exe. Это
> "ломает" весь сеанс работы, т.к.
> отвлекаюсь.

В нетбинс Окно->Вывод->терминал(консоль) (в убунту точно, в масдае хз)
Ещё может быть полезно [это][1]
Тикам образом можно исключить некоторые моменты и на N человекосекунд улучшить свою работу.


  [1]: http://wiki.netbeans.org/Python

Comment: BTW, @sys_dev, вам не приходило в голову, что все извращения типа "сеанса работы" - для скиллов немного выше? Я б даже сказал не "немного", а "намного выше"...

Comment: @klopp: Вы о чем? Какие извращения? Надеюсь Вы понимаете суть термина "сеанс работы" или "работа в потоке" ?

Comment: да, прекрасно понимаю. и что такое "поток", и что такое "погружение". а вы? судя по задаваемым вопросам - явно нет, раз уж обычное рабочее пространство организовать не получается в простых мелочах.

Answer (score 2):

Сделаю ответом, что ли.

> Не получится! Каждый раз задачи разные!

Получится, проверено. Заодно попробую ответить на вопрос "какая IDE" лучше (да любая на самом деле, см. ниже).

Все "одноразовые" задачи я решаю в простеньком текстовом редакторе (mooedit, если интересно). К нему повешены несколько внешних утилит, которые выполняют всякую грязновую работу: проверку синтаксиса, форматирование исходников, сборку дебаг-релиз, запуск с выводом в консоль, запуск отладчика. Конечно, в зависимости от языка, набор действий может отличаться (какой такой дебаг-билд в перле, например; а в c/c++ проверка синтаксиса и компиляция - одно и то же по сути). Но смысл один: сначала отлаживаешь "одностраничный" код (а может и алгоритм вообще, и не на том языке, который нужен в конечном итоге), потом его присоединяешь к большому проекту.

Так вот. Такого "мелкого" кода накапливаются просто горы. Причём мелкого в буквальном смысле, от пары до десятка строк. Раз выкинешь, два выкинешь, а на десятый (или сотый, если совсем тупой) уже задумаешься и вынесешь его в отдельный сниппет. Заодно не поленишься, и напишешь пару строк комментариев: что, зачем, почему.

Вывод такой. Если тебе этот одноразовый код не нужен - да и фиг с ним, выкидывай и пиши заново. Нужен - ищи средства его сохранять и использовать, а не пеняй на "неправильные" IDE. Когда вся работа изначально идёт в мусор, то и париться не о чем в принципе.

Comment: Ну... как бы... приведу метафору "Начали играть свадьбу, а закончили петь за упокой". Вы слишком все по намешали и мысли из разных сторон программерской кухни по намешали в одну кучу. Давайте-ка не будем путать теплое с мягким?! Есть четко обозначенная ситуация в моем посте. Если ситуация не ясна задавайте уточняющие вопросы, ок? Это первое. Второе: не рекомендую говорить за кого бы то ни было то, чего он не говорил! Я к тому что Ваши "не пеняй на "неправильные" IDE" не состоятельны в виду того что я никакую из IDE не ругал! Если Вам хочется помочь мне поймите суть вопроса, иначе следуйте мим

Comment: Я понял суть вопроса так: вы хотите овладеть некоей продвинутой техникой (которой, по сути, описываемая и является). Но что-то в организации работы вам мешает. Что именно - описано в главпосте. Так вот по мне это вполне типичный случай: нужно сначала "в низах" порядок навести, потом и продвижение наверх проще будет. А не наоборот.

Comment: Ваши: "Я понял суть вопроса так". Нет, даже близко к пониманию нет. Прочитайте еще раз или выспитесь :) Всякое бывает, возможно Вы сегодня много работали.

Comment: Попробуйте перечитать свой пост ещё раз. Вы описываете проблемы. Я предполагаю причины их возникновения. Не удивительно, что понимания нет - вы цепляетесь за другое и не хотите это отпускать :)

Answer (score 1):

ну как минимум могу вам посоветовать в место Notepad++ использоваться Geany там написал год, нажал на кнопочку и он его сам запустил где вам нужно и  вывел результат (в частности для Питона, запустил консоль, запустил скрипт, показал вам как это все выглядит.)

И тогда у вас уже останется 2 шага

1. запусти ИДЕ
2. запустил Geany

Удачи вам.

Answer (score 0):

Могу порекомендовать книгу Хант Эндрю "Программист-прагматик". Там в третьей главе есть про инструменты. Даже если не найдёте новых инструментов, время потратите не зря, одна из лучших по разработке из тех, что я встречал.